# multiple logger levels for multiple files in sails.js

Tags: sails.js, winston

I want to create separate files for every log levels, and it should store respective files. says,

```
sails.log.info('Info log');
```

It should store at info.log file.

```
  var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({}),
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'info-file',
      filename: 'info.log',
      level: 'info',
      json: false
    }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'error-file',
      filename: 'error.log',
      level: 'error',
      json: false
    }),
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'debug-file',
      filename: 'debug.log',
      level: 'debug',
      json: false
    })
  ]
});
```

In config/log.js

```
 custom: logger
```

My problem is some logs are not shows in terminal, and info.log and debug.log files has not only info and debug log respectively.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like Winston writes to logs based on their numeric levels. So that error messages will be always written to info log, but info never to error log.

So I think it is better to separate to different instances in config/bootstrap.js:

```
sails.warnLog = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Sentry)({
          name: 'warn-Sentry',
          dsn: '{my account dsn}',
          patchGlobal: true
          level: 'warn'
        })
      ]});

sails.infLog = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Loggly)({
          name: 'info-Loggly',
          subdomain: '{my subdomain}',
          inputToken: '{my input token}'
          level: 'info'
        })
      ]});

sails.verbLog = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
          name: 'verb-console',
          timestamp: true,
          prettyPrint: true,
          colorize: true,
          level: 'verbose'
        })
      ]});
```

And then you can write to log:

```
sails.warnLog.warn('Warning');
sails.infLog.info('Information');
sails.verbLog.verbose('Verbose');
```